# WP_Query duplicates custom posts generated with Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I have a site where users generate posts through an custom post type (movies) through a frontend ACF form. I am using WP_Query to limit the archives to their own posts. It is working, but I get 4 pages of duplicated posts regardless of the user. For example an admin with 20 posts will get the same 20 posts on pages 1-4, and an author with 8 posts will get 4 pages of the same 8 posts.

I have checked if they are revisions (they aren't), I have removed the ACF fields so it is bare-bones WP posts and that doesn't work either.

```
    <?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ):
    global $current_user;

    wp_get_current_user();
    $author_query = array(
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'author'    => $current_user->ID,
        'post_type' => 'batch',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'meta_key'  =>  'batch_name'
    );

    $author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);
    ?>

                <div class="cell" data-title="Name">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_field('movie_name') ?></a>
                </div>

    <?php endwhile;
    else :
        echo "Please log in to view and manage movies";
    endif;
    ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I'm getting all the metadata I want, but I just don't need it 4 times. Thanks in advance for reviewing and helping with this!

Comment: Are you outputting pagination somewhere?

Comment: Yes - thanks for the question as it resolved the issue. The theme (Astra Pro) has a customizer setting for archives and pagination. Switching from 'Pagination' to  'Infinite scroll' reduced it to unique posts, matching the expected output for each author. Thank you so much!